# Counting the appearances in rows for a given value

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table called `private_message` with the fields: `sender` and a `receiver`

I would like to know how many times a specific sender has send a message to a given person, for instance:

```
**Name**     **Times**
David        5
Michael      2
John         1
```

Comment: Are **sender** and **receiver** also tables or fields in your **private_message** table? Just show your tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  sender as 'From',
  receiver as 'To',
  count(receiver) as 'Times'
FROM private_message
GROUP BY sender, receiver
```

Results can be something like:

```
From         To         Times
David        Emil           5
Michael      Møller         2
John         Ringgaard      1
Emil         Ravinder       1
```

Comment: And you did it! - Thank you so much, it works perfectly